# How to programmatically show error message in grid editor field? (Vaadin 13)

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-grid, vaadin-flow

I have a grid for editing beans which have JSR-303 bean level (cross-field) validation implemented for them. Because BeanValidationBinder doesn't support bean-level validation we have our own implementation for validating these cross-field constraints and showing the validation error messages on invalid fields.

Now, this has worked for us fine on other use cases, but now I'm having a problem showing error messages for fields inside grid editor.

Here is a simplified example where all rows are validated when "Save" button is clicked. Product name is found invalid if it isn't "Product". Only the first error that comes across is dealt with, that is fine.

It looks like it all boils down to productGrid.getEditor().editItem(p) -call in validate(List products) -method. If I leave it out, the error message is show in the currently editable field. Of course that might not be the one that has the invalid data.

At first I did try a more elegant solution where user wasn't able to leave invalid row, but at the moment I'd be ready to settle for this if I could get it working. We have use BenValidationBinder in the original code and that handles the single field JSR-303 validation.

I have made the example code using latest "Project Base" application starter (https://vaadin.com/start/latest/project-base) by editing the MainView class like shown below. Running with Vaadin version 13.0.3

Anyone else been having the same issues and hopefully a solution for this?

```
@Route("")
@PWA(name = "Project Base for Vaadin Flow", shortName = "Project Base")
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {

    private Grid<Product> productGrid;
    private TextField code = new TextField();
    private TextField name= new TextField();


    public MainView() {

        List<Product> products = Arrays.asList(new Product("1", "Product"), new Product("2", "Product"));

        productGrid = new Grid<MainView.Product>();
        productGrid.addColumn(Product::getCode)
        .setHeader("Product code")
        .setFlexGrow(1);
        productGrid.addColumn(Product::getName)
        .setEditorComponent(name)
        .setHeader("Product name")
        .setFlexGrow(1);

        Binder<Product> binder = new Binder<>(Product.class);
        binder.bindInstanceFields(this);
        productGrid.getEditor().setBinder(binder);

        productGrid.addItemClickListener(event -> productGrid.getEditor().editItem(event.getItem()));
        productGrid.setItems(products);
        Button save = new Button("Save",
                event -> save(products));

        add(save);
        add(productGrid);
    }



    private void save(List<Product> products) {
        if(validate(products)) {
            Notification.show("Saved: " + String.join(", ", products.stream().map(Product::toString).collect(Collectors.toList())));
        }else {
            Notification.show("Invalid data");
        }
    }

    private boolean validate(List<Product> products) {
        // this only mocks the JSR-303 validation call
        for(Product p:products) {
            if(!p.getName().equals("Product")) {
                productGrid.getEditor().editItem(p);
                name.setErrorMessage("Invalid name, should be: Product");
                name.setInvalid(true);
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public class Product{

        String code;
        String name;

        public Product(String code, String name) {
            super();
            this.code = code;
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getCode() {
            return code;
        }
        public void setCode(String code) {
            this.code = code;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return code + " " + name;
        }
    }

}
```